# Connect to remote Realm with nodeJS for server side and Angular for client side, good practice?

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, graphql, realm

I'm currently trying to figure out which technologies to use in order to maintain "realm features" in a web browser application. I've put together a rudimentary Swift app on iOS which allows for real-time updates coming from realm cloud.

I've spent the last 3-4 hours reading about Nginx, nodeJS, Angular, Express (angular framework) and other technologies.
As far as I've been able to understand, Realm can work with GraphQL which in turn lists nodeJS as a dependency (https://docs.realm.io/sync/getting-started-1/web-based-graphql).

So far I have a Debian 10 server running nginx. I have also installed nodeJS and NPM.

Assuming that I'm on the right path, where do I go from here?
It's proving to be a pretty tough challenge for me but, any help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you for your time.
Regards,

Renato

Comment: from what I've gathered, nginx needs to be configured as a reverse proxy server in order to forward requests to nodeJS

Comment: I have managed to setup nginx proxying requests to nodeJS test app. I followed this tutorial (ignore raspberry part) https://dev.to/guimg/how-to-serve-nodejs-applications-with-nginx-on-a-raspberry-jld